# Report is not running fast?

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

I have two report say Report A and Report B. When I am running two report independently it is running fine. But when I am using Report B as Sub report in Report A. It is not performing well in term of speed.

Comment: check for any issues with parameters

Comment: Parameters are mapped correctly.